# Deadlock in code invoked by Dispatcher.Invoke from multiple threads

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr

I have a strange problem in a mixed mode C#/C++ application which ends up with a deadlock when multiple threads run the same function on the dispatcher thread.

The general structure of the code is like this:

In C++:

```
std::thread t([this,req, dataProvider]() {
    AsyncRequestData(req, dataProvider);
});
SetThreadPriority(t.native_handle(), THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);

t.detach();
```

Inside AsyncRequestData I hand over to a C# method which uses the Dispatcher to run some WPF rendering code:

In C#

```
_dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    var tileRender = new WpfTileRenderer(tileId);                    
    _drawObjectStyleProvider.RefreshTiledStyle = true;
    tileRender.Render(Viewport, filteredRenderList);
});
```

Inside the WpfTileRenderer is a new jump back to native code which does a thread lock. (We use QReadWriteLock, but I suspect we would get the same result with std::mutex or any other synchronization object):

```
void UpdatePointSymbol(int idx, const BasicGeoTypes::GeoPos& pos)
{
    QWriteLocker lock(&_rwlock);
    ...
}
```

What seems to happen is that we have two requests that both are handed over to the dispatcher thread (as expected), but when the first request reaches the QWriteLocker, the execution jumps to the start of a new request. When this second request reaches the same QWriteLocker, it hangs in a deadlock.

The stack looks something like this:

```
NativeBridge.UpdatePointSymbol
[External Code]
WpfTileRenderer.Render
[External Code]
NativeBridge.UpdatePointSymbol
[External Code]
WpfTileRenderer.Render
[External Code]
```

I know that this is a mess, and if we could avoid all the jumping back and forth between native and managed code, I would be a much happier man, but that isn't happening any time soon I'm afraid.

So what I'm asking is basically if there is a known reason that this could happen. I.e could the dispatcher run one method partially and then continue by starting a new method from a different thread that invoked it?

According to the documentation Dispatcher.Invoke is supposed to execute synchronously on the current dispatcher thread, so I would think not?

Any ideas as to what other reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Please share your `Render` method.

Comment: WPF is saddled with a lousy top Google hit, always favor BeginInvoke() over Invoke().  C++ is saddled with a lousy micro-optimization, always favor a lock that supports recursion.

Comment: Synchronously on one thread but not across more than one thread.  You are only locking during Update?  What about Insert and Read?  What I like to do is to have a Read_Write(Mode mode, ref data) where Mode is either read or write.  Then put lock in method and use method for all reading and writing.  This way you can never read and write at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this problem was caused by an out of bounds array operation elsewhere in the code. I suspect that this messed up the stack enough that I got the apparent situation I describe above.

I have seen similar things before and should have checked this closer before posting. Thanks to those who answered and I am really sorry to have wasted your time :-)